# JS - Window's width being decreased below 800px from an amount of pixels that are higher than 800px causes an action to trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

A pretty straight forward question here.

I have a desired action that is called when I change the window size and the screen is below 800px in width.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 800) {
    // this is where the magic happens
  }
});
```

**What I actually want to do is** have the desired action to trigger when the window's width is decreased to below 800 from an amount of pixels that is higher than 800.

For instance, how it functions now is that the desired action will be called any time the window is resized below 800. So adjusting it from 600px -> 800px will cause this action to be triggered again which is not what I want

Comment: So add a flag that says I am over 800 and if it is set, than fire away.

Comment: Thanks epascarello! If you fill this out a little more and post it as an answer, I can give you the Check.

Comment: Depending on what the "magic" is, if all you are adjusting is CSS, then maybe a media query might be a better option.

Comment: the magic is that a sidebar will becomes smaller. The sidebar can be manually increased.

Comment: To complement epascarello's comment http://jsfiddle.net/QAXv7/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var previousWidth; //Define global variable

$(window).ready(function() {
    previousWidth = $(window).width(); //Assign initial width when window is ready
};

$(window).resize(function() {
  var newWidth = $(window).width();
  if (previousWidth >= 800 && newWidth < 800 || //Will trigger when going from larger than 800px to smaller than 800px
      previousWidth < 800 && newWidth >= 800) { //Will trigger when going from smaller than 800px to larger than 800px
    // this is where the magic happens
  }
  previousWidth = newWidth; //Update previous width variable
});
```